# @Url.Action to download a file from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following piece of code to download a file.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("downloadAnnounceFile","Home")?file=@obj.AnnounceFileID" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

In IE it will open a new page and from there can download, for Firefox/Chrome it prompts the user for the file type. obj.AnnounceFileID is the file itself from the database.  It might not always be type pdf.  obj.LinkFileName has the name of the file but I am not sure how to restructure this line to work properly.  I tried the below but it did not work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("downloadAnnounceFile","Home", new { filename = @obj.LinkFileName, file=@obj.AnnounceFileID })" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: "Did not work" *how*?  In what way is this actually failing?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: You can't put the filename as querystring in url?

Comment: The way the code was written when I click the download link it does prompt to open or save the file.  If I choose open it prompts for what file type.  If I save, it saves the file called downloadAnnounceFile with no extention.  I was trying to find a way for the name of the file to be passed so that if I choose open it would know by the file extension.  If I choose save it would save the file as the correct file name.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@` symbols in your second attempt.  You are within a helper, you do not need the `@` symbol to resolve the model values.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("downloadAnnounceFile","Home", 
new { filename = obj.LinkFileName, file=obj.AnnounceFileID })" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

You are trying to do too much work in your first attempt (hand building the URL for the most part).  Let the MVC framework generate your links when possible by using the `@Url.Action()` helper and the `RouteValues` overload.